# how to inherit Folder's properties when adding a new file sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In my library, there are some managed metadata columns. For example, the Company columns as the image.

[image]

I want to know whether it is possible to realize the functions below.

1. If I add a new file to test folder, is it possible to set the folder' Company to the new file by default?
2. I know I can use quick edit to set the folder's properties. Is it also possible to change the files' properties which are in the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to the document Library > Library settings > Column default value settings under General Settings
2. Click the folder that you want to modify in the left
3. Click on the metadata column’s name
4. Select “Use this default value” and insert a value
5. Click OK